# Expected number, got string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code :

```
<vue-speedometer
    :maxSegmentLabels="maxSegmentLabels"
    :segments="segments"
    :value="conversionNum"
    :currentValueText="currentValue()"
    textColor="${textColor}"
    :paddingVertical="paddingVertical"
    :minValue="min()"
    :maxValue="max()"
  />
....
methods: {
  currentValue() {
    return this.$tc('pages.dashboard.groups.ibe.conversion-rate', parseFloat(this.conversionNum).toFixed(1));
  },
  min() {
    return parseFloat(this.averageNum - (2 * this.deviationNum)).toFixed(1);
  },
  max() {
    return parseFloat(this.averageNum + (2 * this.deviationNum)).toFixed(1);
  },
},
....
```

In the browser console I get : `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "minValue". Expected Number with value -288.2, got String with value "-288.2".`. Very strange for me, I return already a number. I tested by return `return 288.2` and is working. Have an idea ?

Comment: [Number.toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

`toFixed` returns a string, doing this should work:

```js
min() {
    return parseFloat((this.averageNum - (2 * this.deviationNum)).toFixed(1));
}
```